# Coerce multiline string to List<String> in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, javafx

One of the outputs of some Model class in my application comes as a multiline string of the following format:

```
System.out.println(str); //output:

row1
row2
row3
row4
```

There might be many values/lines in a string depending on the output, so `str` string is just for example purposes. 
I would like this string to be coerced into `List<String>` if possible, so the printed output will be shown as:

```
List<String> listStr = new ArrayList<String>();
System.out.println(listStr); //output:

[row1, row2, row3, row4]
```

I tried many different approaches e.g.:

```
for (Model modelRow : modelTableView.getItems()) {
            str = modelRow.getInfo();
            System.out.println(str);
            listStr = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split("\n")));
}
```

In most cases only the last value is returned or I get single arrays for all values e.g.:

```
[row1]
[row2]
[row3]
[row4]
```

So, how can I have all values in one List only `[row1, row2, row3, row4]`? What am I missing? Any help or directions would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I avoided using a separator with a `str.split()` method and I queried the cells in the `firstColumn` within the `modelTableView` directly using the following:

```
for (int i=0; i < modelTableView.getItems().size(); i++) {
            str = firstColumn.getCellData(i);
            System.out.println(str);
            listStr = Arrays.asList(str);
}
```

The code doesn't return `NullPointerException` anymore and allows to continue, however the output of `listStr` is just the last element of the original `str` string:

```
System.out.println(listStr);
//output:
[row4]
```

Should I change an iterator within the loop? Any other idea what could go wrong?

Comment: Try `split("\r?\n")`.

Comment: @saka1029 unfortunately, the result was the same as in my comment to the answer below.

Comment: Change `listStr = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split("\n")));` to `listStr.add(str);`

Comment: Or `listStr = Arrays.asList(str);` to `listStr.add(str);`.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson thanks, but I've tried these approaches numerous times with no success. The problem is that `str` gets overwritten every time the for loop is run, so it only holds the last element `row4` after the loop.

Comment: You need to post your complete class. It's hard to pin point your problem from the code you posted.

Comment: In the case where you are getting only the last value, most of the time it means you are doing `List<String> listStr = new ArrayList();` inside the loop and you shouldn't do that.

Comment: You definitely should not be doing `listStr = Arrays.asList(str);`. You should be doing `listStr.add(str);` instead.

Comment: Aslo, you seem to have switched up on us. `str = modelRow.getInfo();` seems to be `str = firstColumn.getCellData(i);` now.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson `modelRow` contains column names which can be extracted using `getInfo()` and the `firstColumn.getCellData(i)` allows to get the column names for the same data but from a different model. Both do the same thing though. In the second case I can use index though.

Comment: You need to post the code for those two methods and the Class that calls these two methods.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson thanks for your ideas, I'm checking them now. I'm sure it has something to do with how I initialised variables in the class. I would like to post the classes, but there are too many of them to add. I'm more interested in ideas what could go wrong than exact solution on my code.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Just checked your ideas, and you were spot on!! Thanks!! So, my mistake was that I declared `List<String> listStr;` at the beginning of the class, where I should define it as `List<String> listStr = new ArrayList<String>();` . Then I can use `listStr.add(str);` as you advised. Thanks a lot. If you are in London, I owe you a pint of beer! ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:

```
List<String> listStr = new ArrayList();
for (Model modelRow : modelTableView.getItems()) {
   str = modelRow.getInfo();
   System.out.println(str);
   listStr.addAll(Arrays.asList(str.split("\n")));
}
```

### EDIT

If you just want to print an array in the way a `List` is printed, you could use:

```
Arrays.toString( array )
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting a NullPointerException for the line where str.split("\n") is located. System.out.println(str); prints all values row by row. Can the separator be incorrect then? I tried with "\r" and there is the same problem.

Comment: str is not null, that's the problem. When falling over on the error, it prints the first value of str and then throws the NullPointerException. It probably has to do something with the separator. I used `System.lineseparator()` instead `"\n"`, but it didn't like it as well

Comment: still no positive results, unfortunately. I've added an edit to my original post if you are still interested in helping me.

Comment: @simtim, what data type is `str`? What does the method Model.getInfo() return?

Comment: @simtim, you are missing the answer from @usagi in your EDIT. The last line should read: `listStr.addAll(Arrays.asList(str));`